# Unable to select the first item after using group by on LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I want to get all `AddOns`(without duplication) with the combination `HealthInsuranceQuotationMemberPlanBenefit` data. `AddOnsID` at `HealthInsuranceQuotationMemberPlanBenefit` is the primary key of `AddOns` table.

```
(from mq in context.HealthInsuranceQuotationMember
join mp in context.HealthInsuranceQuotationMemberPlanBenefit on mq.ID equals mp.HealthInsuranceQuotationMemberID
join ao in context.AddOns on mp.AddOnsID equals ao.ID
where mq.HealthInsurancePlanID == 1 && ao.Category != 2
group mp by new { ao.ID, ao.Name, ao.Category } into g
let fmp = g.First()
select new HealthInsurancePlanAddOnsViewModel
{
    ID = g.Key.ID,
    Name = g.Key.Name,
    CategoryID = (int)g.Key.Category,
    Category = g.Key.Category.ToDescription(),
    Value = fmp.Description,
    Premium = fmp.Premium,
})
.ToList();
```

When I am trying to get the first item of `HealthInsuranceQuotationMemberPlanBenefit` using `fmp = g.First()` it raising following error:

> Processing of the LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
>   KeySelector: new { 
>       ID = (a.ID), 
>       Name = (a.Name), 
>       Category = (a.Category)
>    }, 
>   ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
>       EntityType: HealthInsuranceQuotationMemberPlanBenefit
>       ValueBufferExpression: 
>           (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
>       IsNullable: False
>   )
>   )' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

If I remove the selection of `HealthInsuranceQuotationMemberPlanBenefit(let fmp = g.First(), Value = fmp.Description, Premium = fmp.Premium)` data, it is working.

I investigate the occurred because of `g.First()`

Also, how can I solve & improve this query?